# Vuejs dependency collection

Tags: vue.js

im reading source code of Vue.js

i cant understand this part in `defineReactive` function which turns a property into setter and getter.

my question is :

**why would vue add 2 dependency when the property is an object?(see code below ,#1 and #2 are 2 different dependency**)

```
const dep = new Dep() 

let childOb = !shallow && observe(val)

Object.defineProperty(obj, key, {

    enumerable: true,

    configurable: true,

    get: function reactiveGetter () {

        const value = getter ? getter.call(obj) : val

        if (Dep.target) {

            dep.depend()// #1

        if (childOb) {

            childOb.dep.depend() //#2

       }

    if (Array.isArray(value)) {

        dependArray(value)

   }

 }

return value

}

}
```

Comment: Because the whole object has to change when i child is changed.

Comment: but it has already a Dep ,`const dep = new Dep() `,why put another 'dep' as a property in the Observer?

Comment: Even the childs should be reactive

Answer (score 0):

The `#1` dep is used to notify about an assignment, like `o.name = 'new name'`

`#2` is used to notify non-assignment changes, including set, delete and array apis(push, pop etc)